# AWS RDS and PGAdmin

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I am working on a personal Django project and plan on using a PGSQL DB on AWS RDS.
Tutorials I see always show the process of linking RDS dbs to PGAdmin and I am wondering if this step really is necessary/vital. Would there be consequences (apart from not having access to all the benefits of PGAdmin of course) if I skipped it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd also be spared all the pains associated with pgAdmin. Use the PostgreSQL client of your choice!

Comment: Thank you, can I ask you what client you would recommand for a PGSQL newbie ?

Comment: I always use `psql`, but have a look [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe pgAdmin is an open source free tool. If you want improvements then you can contribute as well. Or, raise the feature requests/suggestions to pgAdmin devs on how it can be improved.